# How to get current and next month dates in php/html?

Tags: php, html, date

I  have a php code as shown below in which I want to show current and next month dates in php. Below are the two functions which I am using in order to show current and next month dates.

**html/php code (current month function and next month function):**

```
<!-- current month function START -->

<?php
function buildDateSelectionCurrentMonth($month)
{
    # array will hold our months
    $months = [
        str_pad($month, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT),
        str_pad(($month + 1), 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT),
    ];

    # will hold our HTML
    $output = '';

    # got our months now, let's iterate over them

    foreach ($months as $index => $month) {
        $year = date('Y');

        // Adjust month and date if necessary:
        if ($month == 13) {
            $month = 1;
            $year++;
        }

        if ($index == 0) {
            # create timestamp for the first of a month
            # then get number of days for that month
            $numberOfDaysMonth = date('t', strtotime($year . '-' . $month . '-01'));

            # we can now loop over the days and fill the output string
            for ($i = 1; $i <= $numberOfDaysMonth; $i++) {
                $output .= '<div class="select-date" style="margin-right:30px; margin-top:20px;">
<input type="date" class="class-sitting-date" name="class_sitting_date_current_month[]" readonly="readonly" value="' . $year . '-' . $month . '-' . str_pad($i, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT) . '">
</div>';
            }
        }
    }

    return $output;
}

<!-- current month function END -->


<!-- next month function START -->
<?php
function buildDateSelectionNextMonth($month)
{
    # array will hold our months
    $months = [
        str_pad($month, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT),
        str_pad(($month + 1), 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT),
    ];

    # will hold our HTML
    $output = '';

    # got our months now, let's iterate over them

    foreach ($months as $index => $month) {
        $year = date('Y');

        // Adjust month and date if necessary:
        if ($month == 13) {
            $month = 1;
            $year++;
        }

        if ($index == 0) {
            # create timestamp for the first of a month
            # then get number of days for that month
            $numberOfDaysMonth = date('t', strtotime($year . '-' . $month . '-01'));

            # we can now loop over the days and fill the output string
            for ($i = 1; $i <= $numberOfDaysMonth; $i++) {
                $output .= '<div class="select-date" style="margin-right:30px; margin-top:20px;">
<input type="date" class="class-sitting-date" name="class_sitting_date_next_month[]" readonly="readonly" value="' . $year . '-' . $month . '-' . str_pad($i, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT) . '">
</div>';
            }
        }
    }

    return $output;
}

?>
<!-- next month function END -->
```

**html/php code (current month dates and next month dates):**

```
<!-- Current Month Dates START -->
<div class="sitting-days">
    <h4 name="dates-selection" style="text-align:center;"><a name="dates-selection">Select Date</a>
    </h4>
    <?php echo buildDateSelectionCurrentMonth(date('n')); ?>     // Line Y
</div>
<!-- Current Month Dates END -->


<!-- Next Month Dates START -->
<div class="sitting-days" style="margin-left:30px;">
    <h4 style="text-align:center;">Select Date</h4>
    <div class="sitting-days">
        <?php echo buildDateSelectionNextMonth(date('n')+1); ?>   // Line Z
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Next Month Dates END -->
```

At Line Y and Line Z  its currently displaying November and December dates

When the current month is September then it will display September 2020 dates and October 2020 dates and vice-versa.

**Problem Statement:**

Just for fun, at Line Y and Line Z I did the following changes:

**At Line Y:**

```
echo buildDateSelectionCurrentMonth(12);
```

**At Line Z**

```
echo buildDateSelectionNextMonth(13);
```

The reason why I did that because I want to check whether it will display January 2021 dates or not.

I noticed that it didn't display January 2021 dates at Line Z although it was displaying December 2020 dates at Line Y.

I am wondering what changes I need to make in the php code above so that it displays `January 2021 dates` when the `current month is December`.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `buildDateSelectionNextMonth(13)`, the `$months` array ends up containing:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 13
    [1] => 14
)
```

Your code that adjusts the month and date only accounts for when `$month == 13`, not when it is 14:

```
// Adjust month and date if necessary:
        if ($month == 13) {
            $month = 1;
            $year++;
        }
```

You also have two nearly identical functions: `buildDateSelectionCurrentMonth()` and `buildDateSelectionNexMonth()`. This is redundant and only makes things more difficult. Even stranger, these functions create an array of two months, but because of this line they only end up processing the first of those two months:

```
if ($index == 0) {
```

Your best bet is to write a single function that will output the desired dates for the given month, and if that month is 13 then it will assume January of next year:

```
function buildDateSelectionForMonth($month)
{
    # will hold our HTML
    $output = '';

    $year = date('Y'); // assume current year

    // Adjust month and date if necessary:
    if ($month == 13) {
        $month = 1;
        $year++;
    }

    # create timestamp for the first of a month
    # then get number of days for that month
    $numberOfDaysMonth = date('t', strtotime($year . '-' . $month . '-01'));

    # we can now loop over the days and fill the output string
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $numberOfDaysMonth; $i++) {
        $output .= '<div class="select-date" style="margin-right:30px; margin-top:20px;">
<input type="date" class="class-sitting-date" name="class_sitting_date_next_month[]" readonly="readonly" value="' . sprintf( '%04d-%02d-%02d', $year, $month, $i ) . '">
</div>';
    }

    return $output;
}
```

To get the dates for the current month:

```
buildDateSelectionForMonth( date('m') );
```

To get the dates for next month:

```
buildDateSelectionForMonth( date('m') + 1 );
```

Comment: I have updated my question. Let me know if it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Php offers build in date functions/classes that are easier than building everything manually

```
<?php
function buildDateSelectionNextMonth($month) {
    $stringStartDate = date('Y').'-'.str_pad($month, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT)'-01';
    $startDate = new \DateTime($stringStartDate);
    $maxDate = (new \DateTime($startDate))->modify('+2 months');
    $output = '';
    for($d = new \DateTime($startDate) ; $d < $maxDate ; $d->modify('+1 day')) {
        $output .= '<div>...'.$d->format('Y-m-d').'...</div>';
    }
    return $output;
}
```